# C# - SqlDataReader missing columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader, sqlclient

Here is my records like in the table below.
[sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Ff2.png)

My SQL query is

```
select Category_NM as 'Kategoriler', avg(Payment) as 'Ortalamalar' 
from Islem 
where Category_Type = 'Gider' 
group by Category_NM
```

And my code:

```
public SqlDataReader DataReader(string Query_)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query_, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    return dr;
}
```

and

```
SqlDataReader dr = sınıf.DataReader("select Category_NM as 'Kategoriler',AVG(Payment) as 'Ortalamalar' from Islem where Category_Type = 'Gider' group by Category_NM");
dr.Read();

chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

while (dr.Read())
{
    // MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dr[0]+""+dr[1]));
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dr[0],dr[1]);
}
dr.Close();
```

The problem ıs reader does not read all records - like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6IVG.png)

Comment: Post code and error messages as text in the question, not links. Images can't be copied, compiled, tested or googled

Comment: As for the code only processing 2 columns, that's what the code you wrote does. It only reads two columns, the first (0) and the second. Have you tried reading the third one with `dr[2]`? Since you only posted part of an image it's impossible to see whether the SQL query includes all columns

Comment: By the way, you really shouldn't do this: the connection, command and reader need to be in `using` blocks in order to correctly dispose them. Do *not* cache the connection object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call `dr.Read()` at the first go and then iterate them.

Correction:

```
SqlDataReader dr = sınıf.DataReader("select Category_NM as 'Kategoriler',AVG(Payment) as 'Ortalamalar' from Islem where Category_Type = 'Gider' group by Category_NM");
chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
while (dr.Read())
{
    // MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dr[0]+""+dr[1]));
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dr[0], dr[1]);
}
dr.Close();
```

each `Read()` move the row pointer ahead.
So first `Read()` skip first record.

If you need check if there is any record and then `chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;` it is enough to use `if (dr.HasRows)` like:

```
if(dr.HasRows)
{
   chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
   //Iterate dr like while(dr.Read()){...}
}
```

But you have to know that your `while` block logic always read a Record at position `0` and fetch values at `col0` and `col1`, if you need read all record you can iterate by `foreach` or `for` something like:

```
foreach (DbDataRecord s in dr)
 {
    string kategoriler= s.GetString(0);
    string ortalamalar = s.GetString(1);
 }
```

or `while`:

```
while(dr.Read())
{
    var kat = dr["Kategoriler"].ToString();
    var ort = dr["Ortalamalar"].ToString();
}
```